# Is libSoX thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sox

I am using libSox, the audio processing library in a multi-threaded application. Several threads may call the libsox functions simultaneously. I was wondering if libsox was thread-safe since I am getting this random crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not completely threadsafe.
This commit **[here](http://sox.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=sox/sox;a=commit;h=381a7bd)** tells so.

Comment: So from reading the commit message: Is it thread-safe if I do not touch the sox_globals structure? What else is shared between threads?